# Given perpendicular distance d on line1, how to find point P on line2 in C++?

Tags: c++, math, geometry, 2d

Given line1, line2, and distance d, I want to write a program to calculate the point on Line2 that is perpendicular to Line1, and the perpendicular distance is d.

[image]

Does anyone know where to start?
In C++ or any other programming language.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And if you have a complex problem that you don't know how to begin solving, then split it up into smaller and less complex sub-problems. Continue to split your sub-problems until none can be split further. Then start solving each very small and very simple sub-problem, putting them together to solve the larger and more complex sub-problems. At the end you should hopefully have solved the original large and complex problem. I also recommend you properly test the solutions for each sub-problem before continuing with the next.

Comment: you need to do the maths first. Once you know the algorithm its just a matter of writing it down, but if you cannot do it with pen an paper its to early to think about the code

Comment: If you don't know the formula then [math.se] would be a better place to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalize line1 equation

```
L = sqrt(a1*a1+b1*b1)
a11 = a1 / L
b11 = b1 / L
c11 = c1 / L
```

Now for arbitrary point `(x,y)` length of perpendicular projection onto `line1` is

```
d = a11*x + b11*y + c11
a11*x + b11*y + (c11-d) = 0
```

for vertical `line2` case `(b2==0) and (b11 != 0)`

```
x = c2/a2
a11*c2/a2 + b11*y + (c11-d) = 0
y = -(a11*c2/a2 + (c11-d)) / b11
```

so needed point is `(c2/a2, -(a11*c2/a2 + (c11-d)) / b11)`

For general case, if `(a11*b2 != b11*a2)` (non-parallel line case):

```
y = - (a2*x + c2)/b2
a11*x - b11*(a2*x+c2)/b2 + (c11-d) = 0
a11*x - b11*a2*x/b2  + (c11 - d - b11*c2/b2) = 0
x*(a11 - b11*a2/b2) =  (d + b11*c2/b2 - c11)
x = (d + b11*c2/b2 - c11) / (a11 - b11*a2/b2)
```

and point is `((d + b11*c2/b2 - c11) / (a11 - b11*a2/b2), y for this x)`

Answer (score -1):

[image]

@463035818_is_not_a_number is right, you need to do the math first.
I would suggest to find the intersection point and the angle first: https://www.cuemath.com/geometry/intersection-of-two-lines/
Then you can calculate 'c' and then you can write sin(alpha)=d/c equation with (x,y). So you'll have line2 and the equation that you get in terms of x and y which gives you 2 equations with 2 unknowns. hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Given a line equation for line1 with `y1 = m1 * x1 + b1` we move this line in normal direction with the given distance d and have then `y1 = m1 * x1 + (b1 +/- d)`. As you can see we could have 2 possible solutions if the lines are not parallel.

Now with the new line we search the intersection with line2, which is given by the formula:

Line Equations:

`Line_1_with_d => y1 = m1 * x1 + (b1 +/- d)`

`Line_2 => y2 = m2 * x2 + b2`

Intersection Equations:

`Point_x = (b2 - (b1 +/- d)) / (m1 - m2)` (you will get here a problem if they are parallel)

`Point_y = (m1 * (b2 - (b1 +/- d))) / ((m1 - m2) + (b1 +/- d))`

If the lines are parallel (which you should check first) you can test if the given distance d matches the distance of the lines:

`d = (|b2 - b1|) / (sqrt(m^2 + 1))` (`m1 == m2` if parallel)